# Strange currency format when updating table

Tags: delphi, ado

We are updating an SQL Server table using `TAdoQuery` in a normal open/edit/post sequence.

Everything works fine here but the update fails at our clients site.  Using SQL Server Profiler we have found the following:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE "Eclipse".."Loan"
SET "Balance"=@P1,"Status"=@P2,"Act"=@P3
WHERE "Rec"=@P4 AND "Balance"=@P5 AND "Status"=@P6 AND "Act"=@P7',
N'@P1 money,@P2 varchar(8000),@P3 bit,@P4 int,@P5 money,@P6 varchar(8000),@P7 bit',
$0.0000,'Cancelled',0,272188,$-13879.-4400,'Active',1
```

The interesting part is parameter P5 defined as money and given the value $-13879.-4400

We can not find out why this is happening or what we can do about it.

Comment: You'll need to show us the Delphi code which calls the stored procedure, including variable declarations and values.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some code like this:  var
  X : currency;
  N,M:integer;
  S : string;
begin
  X := -12345.6789;
  M := trunc(X);
  N := trunc(10000*(X-M));
  S := '$' + inttostr(M)+'.'+inttostr(N);

Comment: @Jim If you're not going to provide any additional information, the question is pointless and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have different locale and/or regional settings configured on client and SQL Server machines. For example, SQL might be configured with English (United States) locale, while client machine (where Delphi builds your code) might have German, French (or whatever) locale.

In runtime client submits an ADO query, assuming that Server accepts `€`  as a currency symbol, `,` (comma) as a decimal separator and a leading zero. At the other end Server expects currency symbol to be `$`, decimal separator `.` and no leading zero.

The suggestion is to check out `fs: TFormatSettings` object and use it to set correct regional settings expected by both parties.